# alternative proof that a function is homogeneous of degree one

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof, supremum-and-infimum

Given a (profit) function of the form

$$
\pi(p) = \sup \{p.y:y \in Y\}
$$, where $p \in R_+^k$ is a positive (price) vector and $Y \in R^k$ is a (production-possibility) set.

I need to proof that $\pi()$ is homogeneous of degree one i.e. $\pi(p \alpha)=\alpha \pi(p)$ for $\alpha \geq 0$.

According to my professor, the proof goes like this:
For all $y \in Y$,
$$ \pi(p) \geq p.y  $$
$$ \alpha \pi(p) \geq \alpha p.y $$
$$ \alpha \pi(p) \geq \sup \alpha p.y $$
$$ \alpha \pi(p) \geq \pi(\alpha p)$$
On the other hand,

$$ \frac{1}{\alpha} \pi(\alpha p) \geq  \pi(\frac{\alpha}{\alpha} p.y) $$
$$ \pi(\alpha p) \geq  \alpha \pi(p.y) $$,
 thus
$$ \alpha \pi(p) = \pi(p \alpha)$$

No problems with this proof, but before I saw it, I tried to make a proof on my own.

I got something like this,

$$\alpha \pi(p) = \alpha \sup \{p.y:y \in Y\} =  \sup \{(\alpha p).y:y \in Y\} = \pi( p \alpha )$$
since I'm not confident with supremum, and my proof is much shorter, I'm suspecting that I have some mistake, or I'm disregarding some situation such as when $\pi(p)=\infty$.